# mysql unique combination of 2 column values sort by another column

Tags: mysql

i have sample data like this

```
------------------------------------------
message_id | sender_id | receiver_id | message
------------------------------------------

1 | 101 | 102 | hello
2 | 102 | 101 | i am fine
3 | 103 | 101 | where are you?
4 | 101 | 103 | i am at my home
5 | 103 | 101 | ok
6 | 101 | 102 | so whats up?
7 | 102 | 104 | i am so busy
8 | 105 | 101 | hey
```

I would like the latest message from each dialogue in which user 101 is a participant

Expecting output

```
8 | 105 | 101 | hey
6 | 101 | 102 | so whats up?
5 | 101 | 103 | i am at my home
```

i need mysql query for this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: yes i need latest row from each conversation.
its all one-to-one conversation.
not a group chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT LEAST(sender_id,receiver_id) user1
            , GREATEST(sender_id,receiver_id) user2
            , MAX(message_id) message_id 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE 101 IN (sender_id,receiver_id)
        GROUP 
           BY user1
            , user2
     ) b 
    ON b.message_id = a.message_id;
```

or just

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(message_id) message_id 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE 101 IN (sender_id,receiver_id)
        GROUP 
           BY LEAST(sender_id,receiver_id) 
            , GREATEST(sender_id,receiver_id) 
     ) b 
    ON b.message_id = a.message_id;
```

This can also be written as follows. I doubt it makes much difference to performance...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(message_id) message_id
         FROM 
            ( SELECT message_id
                   , receiver_id user2 
                FROM my_table 
               WHERE sender_id = 101
               UNION
              SELECT message_id
                   , sender_id 
                FROM my_table 
               WHERE receiver_id = 101
            ) x
        GROUP
           BY user2
     ) b 
    ON b.message_id = a.message_id;
```

Actually, in my own limited tests, the first queries complete in half the time of the last one.

Comment: The query is fine. Either way, "did not work" is not an acceptable response on SO.

Comment: i added order by message id desc now it works as expected. thanks your help.
it is taking 0.65sec is there any way to optimize? i have about 1.8 billion rows

Comment: sorry its 1.8millions

Comment: If an answer has been helpful, consider upvoting it. If an answer has solved the problem, consider accepting that answer. If an answer does both, consider doing both. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

If you give bit code or your file sql will be good to answering your question.
Try this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection," SELECT * FROM your table WHERE sender_id = '101' OR receive_id = '101' GROUP BY message_id ");
return $query;
```